# How can I add viewController as subview?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a UIViewController that contain a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354132/create-a-uiviewcontroller-that-contain-a-uiviewcontroller)

I have a parent view with many subview in different viewcontroller because a part of screen is same with every view, so i create only needed part of other screen in other view controller nib.
Then i planed when a view need load i will just add it like subview and remove it switch to another screen 
it's just simple

```
viewController = []...
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
currentView = viewController.view;
currentView.setFrame :(aFrame); // to move to different part (all screen has a common part)
```

But my problem is new view is added to screen but it always stay at (0,0) no matter how frame i did set.
But weird thing is if i tap at part of screen in new frame it will be behavior like view was moved there but screen not redraw.

What wrong? Please help

Comment: set the frame size before adding subview

Comment: Why can not you set the frame of view and then add to ViewController and then add [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

Comment: @Legolas: I tried already, but no luck, subview still not redraw,

Comment: Try to write more clear, consider punctuation. And first check for [dublicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354132/create-a-uiviewcontroller-that-contain-a-uiviewcontroller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> i create only need only need part of other screen in other view controller nib

I think that the problem could be related to the way the view is created in Interface Builder. Specifically, if you create a nib file and choose the "View" type, then a nib is created that contains a view with a fixed size (screen size).

So, my suggestion is trying and create a nib using the "Empty" template and then adding a UIView from the library. In this case, you will be allowed to set the view size (in the third pane of the Inspector). Possibly this will fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, this was issue. i found it and resize the view size in IB then it work. I try to animation this subview only but it still animate all screen :(

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

1. Create a UIView with the frame size that you want.

   UIView *testView;
   // alloc it and set frame size
2. Add `viewController.view` as a subview to the `testView`.
3. Add the `testView` with that frame size in mind and add that as a subview to `self.view`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
[currentView setNeedsDisplay];
```