# Create a UIViewController that contain a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have a `UIViewController` that allow me to display some text into a view.
I want to add an input method without add it directly into this view controller, this input method will be a button or a `UITextField`.
This input method will be a lot, but it will be use one at time chosing it from setting so a I won't to have a `UIViewController` that control all of this.

What I want is know how it's possible to split the output view (controller) with each input view (controller)?

You can image to have a text view on the top of the screen and some other view at the bottom and I will to separate the logic of the second view from the logic of the first one

Is it clear?

Comment: I wrote an [example](https://github.com/alfiehanssen/ios-viewcontroller-containment) of how to use `UIViewController` containment, might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible to have 2 UIViewControllers on screen at any time!  There are a few ways to go about this:

Using One Main View:  Add the second ViewController's view as a subview

Using Interface Builder: Drag in a UIViewController Object, set it's class, then hook it's View outlet to a UIView in the first ViewController.

Child View Controller: As it's name implies, the -`addChildViewViewController:` method will add a new ViewController as well, then add it's view as a subview.

Comment: After adds the viewcontorller with Interface builder i get this error :
"Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination."

Comment: In -applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: you need to adda root view controller.  google around, the error has a million answers.

Comment: addChildViewController is iOS 5 only.

Comment: @lorean, if that's a problem, then he can do view controller containment the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Just add the controller as a child controller (`[UIViewController addChildController:]` and its view (`[controller.view addSubview:childController.view]`).